# Android Studio Dolphin Firebase Issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio Dolphin RC1.

I am finding it difficult to configure the Firebase Firestore DB. Initial setup need to incorporate

Project-level build.gradle (/build.gradle):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13' - My problem

  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
}
```

But the new IDE is not supporting it. This is the new Project-level build.gradle (/build.gradle):

. Where should I put the classpath?

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "TestApp"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
  dependencies {
    // Added the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
   

  }
}
```

Remove google() and mavenCentral(). Add the gradle dependency.
then use this version in `gradle-Wraper.properties file`.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```